# kodi crash on raspberry pi 4 when playing h265 videos

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, kodi

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian. Trying to play h265 videos. Kodi crashes with the following output:

```
rpi_ctrl_ffmpeg_init
 id=0x97703520
can't open /dev/argon-hevcmem
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

If I check /dev with ls, /dev/argon-hevcmem does not exist.

Other formats play fine.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem SOLVED!

The latest kernel commited by Hexxeh lacks valid VideoCore libraries, hence the HEVC playback crashing Kodi.

To solve that issue, I did (use 'rpi-update' with caution):

~$ sudo rpi-update e1050e94821a70b2e4c72b318d6c6c968552e9a2

… then:

~$ sudo reboot

That command downgrades the kernel back to version 4.19.118-v7l+ #1311, so Kodi can play HEVC/H.265 videos again.

Let me know if that works for you, too.

EDIT: typo.

Comment: You're welcome. Next time, I'll read the CHANGELOG on GitHub Hexxeh's page before updating the kernel/firmware!

Answer (score 0):

I created some udev rules as follows:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="rpivid-h264mem", SYMLINK+="argon-h264mem"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="rpivid-hevcmem", SYMLINK+="argon-hevcmem"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="rpivid-intcmem", SYMLINK+="argon-intcmem"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="rpivid-vp9mem", SYMLINK+="argon-vp9mem"
```

to make all this work until the Kodi binary package (from pipplware I'm assuming you're using) incorporates this commit https://github.com/PIPplware/xbmc/commit/c6c6dc0aa9cb58701b2d8102b9a0750a7c32f840